# Can we get Parasara Bhattar's 171 Namavalis extracted from Vishnu sahasranamam?

Tags: mantras, vishnu-sahasranama

We know that Vishnu Sahasranamam comprises of 1000 names of Maha Vishnu. Out of these 1000 names, Parasara bhattar had picked 171 namavalis which is very useful, for example - 'Om Bhuve Namaha' can help to get wealth and 'Om Sarvapraharanayudhaya Namaha' can help get rid of difficulties of all sorts.

Does anyone have the 171 namavalis? If they put the namavali with meaning it will be useful for the members in this community to chant daily.

Comment: Whats the problem in Chanting entire Sahastranaam daily?

Comment: @Yogi--I have to travel for office. Daily reciting Namalwar's thiruvaimozhi 11 slokas besides regular slokas. Only on Saturdays will recite Vishnu sahasranamam. That is why I asked.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, we can get Parasara Bhattar's 171 Namavalis extracted from Vishnu sahasranamam. The file whose link is provided at the end of the answer has the following preface

> One great Vaishnava devotee of yore named Parasara Bhatta while writing
>   the commentary has selected approx. 171 names out ofthousand names in
>   Vishnu Sahasranama and has described the special benefit which
>   will accrue by chanting each name in the form of a separate Mantra. A
>   summary of that selected list of 171 names is enclosed. Extracted from
>   Commentary by Parasara Bhattaon Vishnu Sahasranamam

[Link for source file](http://swamishantanandapurimaharaj.org/mantras/Mantra%2031.pdf)